# Disable CloudFlare email obfuscation without disabling it from cloudfare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudflare

> On my live site I have on email obfuscation under CloudFlare settings. Now on my site, I am not able to see any emails is just show  [email protected] link which redirected to CloudFlare message. Also, this is not happening with all email address see images.

[image]

[image: email protected image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> After adding following tags I was able to see emails again and also not need to change CloudFlare settings.

```
<!--email_off--> example@ex.com <!--/email_off-->
```